# I have a problem that my css is not working in browser when .css file is in another folder but its working in Windows pc same way

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I am keeping both index.html/php file in the same directory, then CSS is working fine on browsers. But when I am putting the same .css file in css folder and changing the code according to the file path, it's not working.

I searched a lot and tried different methods.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

`href="style.css"` is working fine but this `href="css/style.css"` connection is not.

Comment: The path to the file must be incorrect. Try `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: i have tried this too but still the issue is same.

Comment: in which language, simple HTML linking or angular or react stuff ?